# Why doesn't 'this.driver = driver', do the same as 'PageFactory.initElements(driver,this)'?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, page-objects

I have a page object with im trying to instantiate so that I can perform methods on it in my tests like goto etc.

But when I try to use it with `PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);`. The browser only opens when invoked with my go-to the method and then immediately quits with a nullpointer error.

If I use `this.driver = driver`. It works as intended. So the work around is to call both methods.. but that's duplicating my code...

```
public Homepage(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
    }
```

Here is my simple test method.

```
public void Goto()
{
    System.out.println("Navigating");
    driver.get("https://www.practiceground.org/");
}
```

And my actual test.

```
@Test
    public void Test_All_The_Navbar_Links()
    {
        var homepage = new Homepage(driver);

        homepage.Goto();
    }
```

Edit:

Stacktrack as requested.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at PageObjects.Homepage.Goto(Homepage.java:25)
    at FirstTestCase.Test_All_The_Navbar_Links(FirstTestCase.java:11)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: Can you please paste full stacktrace?

Comment: Post edited with it included.

Comment: `PageFactory.init()` takes PageObject class and return its instance. Instead you are passing an instace (`this`) and ignoring the result.

Comment: Sorted it.

I created a `init` method that calls `homepage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Homepage.class);` and then use `this.driver = driver;` in my page class.

I would prefer to pass driver to my page once. But this seems to work.